# Using gdb to disassemble full program

Tags: gdb

I just started using gdb for basic debugging of active processes. I know I can use disassemble  or diassemble(memory address) or disassemble (start), (end). However, I want to disassemble the whole program at once. Is there any way to get the end address of a process I've attached to?

Edit: And I would like to do so without using layout asm

Comment: `I want to disassemble the whole program at once`. Why not use: `objdump -d your-program`?

Comment: The objdump formatting is what I want. But I don't think thats possible for a process?

Comment: No, my point was to run `objdump` for your program.